# Button in Kendo Grid, on click update field

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In my Kendo Grid I have a column that I'd like to contain a button.

On clicking this button, I'd like to populate one of fields in the grid (called TradesmanId) with an ID that is available to a javacript function (it is the ID of a logged in user).

This ID should sit in the field until the save changes event on the grid is called.

I had thought about defining the column like this, but I wonder if a command column would work better?

```
.Columns(trdcol =>
                    {
                        trdcol.Bound(f => f.TradeHrs).Title("Man Hours").Width(45);
                        trdcol.Bound(f => f.TradeDate).Title("Time Date").Width(77).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(TradeDate, 'hh:mm dd/MM/yyyy') #");
                        trdcol.Bound(p => p.TradesmanId).ClientTemplate("<button id='button' class='k-button'><span class='k-icon k-i-check-outline'></span> #= TradesmanId#</button>").Title("Signature").Width(85);
                    })
```

Answer (score 1):

What you did is fine. You can just add a class to your button and then add a click handler that'll do the following:

```
$(document).on("click", "buttton.my-class", function(e) {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid($(this).closest("tr").data("uid"));
    dataItem.TradesmanId = getLoggedInUserId(); //your javascript function returning the user id
    grid.refresh();
})
```